# difference between methods to use multiple ip addresses

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet, ifconfig

I have a question about using multiple ip addresses on one NIC card.
I have searched, and found some methods.

### Method 1 (Adding new ip, 192.168.201.131)

- Add new ip by using `ip addr add` command

  `$ sudo ip addr add 192.168.201.131/24 dev eno1`
- Check the changes

  `$ ip addr
  2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
  link/ether 70:5a:0f:4d:6c:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 192.168.201.130/24 brd 192.168.201.255 scope global eno1
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet 192.168.201.131/24 scope global secondary eno1
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 fe80::ca93:7382:b896:96ef/64 scope link
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

### Method 2 (Adding new ip, 192.168.201.132)

- To modify ethernet interface

  `$ sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces`
- Append following lines on interfaces

  `auto eno1:0
  iface eno1:0 inet static
  address 192.168.201.132
  netmask 255.255.255.0`
- Check the changes

  `$ ip addr
  2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
  link/ether 70:5a:0f:4d:6c:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 192.168.201.130/24 brd 192.168.201.255 scope global eno1
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet 192.168.201.131/24 scope global secondary eno1
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet 192.168.201.132/24 brd 192.168.201.255 scope global secondary eno1:0
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 fe80::ca93:7382:b896:96ef/64 scope link
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

### After adding two ips(192.168.201.131 and 192.168.201.132)

- I checked `ifconfig`

`eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:5a:0f:4d:6c:e7
          inet addr:192.168.201.130  Bcast:192.168.201.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ca93:7382:b896:96ef/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:247227538 errors:0 dropped:18734853 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:153950869 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:202326646374 (202.3 GB)  TX bytes:85834800896 (85.8 GB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:d1000000-d1020000`


`eno1:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:5a:0f:4d:6c:e7
          inet addr:192.168.201.132  Bcast:192.168.201.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:16 Memory:d1000000-d1020000`

- There is no 192.168.201.131 on eno1 which had been added by Method 1
- Ping to two new ips(*.131, *.132) is working.
- I can't figure out what's the difference between these two methods.

Answer (score 1):

In your user case, responding to ping, is the same net effect.

The first method, obviously, modifies your kernel routing table with route command manually / directly at a lower level if you will.

See https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-is-a-routing-table/ for an explanation of the kernel routing table.

In the second example, you are editing a configuration file, `/etc/network/interfaces`, which does the same thing, in essence, via the networking scripts. See [man interfaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/interfaces.5.html) for details.

Obviously, as a part of the networking scripts, the kernel routing table is updated via ifup / ifdown and `/etc/network/interfaces` / network scripts have additional configuration options and the possibility of custom pre/post up/down scripts thus you have more options with `/etc/network/interfaces`.

The first method is temporary, and will not survive a reboot (although you could add a custom init script to do so).

The second method will survive a reboot. At the time of boot, the networking scripts are a part of the boot process and other services that are dependent on them will wait for the network to come up (apache, ftp, samba, nfs, etc). If you simply call route during boot such services may error out if they are run before your route command.

Hope all that helps or at least points you in the right direction for the information you want.